# How to write a method that takes a general iterator as input argument?

Tags: c++

Now I have a bunch of these methods ( you can tell how ugly it looks like):

```
void ConvertUtility::ConvertEdgeIndexList(const list<EdgeIndex> &edgeIndex)
{

     list<EdgeIndex>::const_iterator sit;
     for(sit=edgeIndex.begin(); sit!=edgeIndex.end(); sit++)
     {

     }
}


void ConvertUtility::ConvertEdgeIndexList(const vector<EdgeIndex> &edgeIndex)
{

     vector<EdgeIndex>::const_iterator sit;
     for(sit=edgeIndex.begin(); sit!=edgeIndex.end(); sit++)
     {

     }
}
```

Is there anyway I can aggregate these two functions into one single function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
template<typename C>
void ConvertUtility::ConvertEdgeIndexList(C const& edgeIndex)
{
     typename C::const_iterator sit;
     for(sit=edgeIndex.begin(); sit!=edgeIndex.end(); ++sit)
     {                                      //        ^^ Prefer pre-increment on iterators.

     }
}
```

PS. Stackoverflow may be a better site for this type of question.

Answer (score 9):

I would have a function taking a generic iterator range, in the style of the standard algorithms.

```
template <typename Iterator>
void ConvertUtility::ConvertEdgeIndexList(Iterator start, Iterator end)
{
    for (Iterator sit = start; sit != end; ++sit)
    {

    }
}
```

If you need a specific type of iterator (e.g. ForwardIterator, or RandomAccessIterator), then the template parameter name is a good place to document that.